# Windows Bash Terminal takes over 10 seconds to load

Tags: bash, terminal, git

When starting up **Git Bash** in a Windows terminal or VScode terminal, the screen is blank for 10 - 15 seconds before it initializes to having a working directory and cursor. After init, it runs fine.

This has been happening for months. I want to resolve this without reformatting the device, yet I feel this may be coming for me.

I've searched for this on Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow but cannot find any other questions like this.

I'm on **Windows 10** using the git bash terminal.

I have tried:

- Re-booting
- Clearing .bash_history but this had no effect.
- Re-installed Git Bash
- Checked processes running with `ps` (none running)

Comment: When you say "Windows terminal" do you mean Windows Terminal the UWP application, or do you mean something else?

Comment: @Ramhound - yep, the Windows Terminal UWP application, and also the the VSCode terminal.

Comment: So is the issue just the amount of time it is taking for Git Bash to initiate? What are your computer's specs? Have you done any research regarding Git Bash initiating slowly or how to optimize its initiation processes?

Comment: Yes I've tried to find out how to optimize but it hasn't worked. I think that it is a certain issue as the computer is 12 months old but only happened the last few months. 
laptop specs 12th gen i7 intel, 16g ram.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with Git Bash being extremely slow when connected to a VPN.

Another common fix is completely removing `.bash_profile` in your Home directory.

Another fix is ensuring your `HOME` Environment Variable is set to your user folder `C:\Users\YourUser`.

Here's a very thorough [superuser link](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) explaining how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, I am not using a VPN, tried those solutions to no avail, unfortunately. I reckon it's something in the system doing it, as the computer is 12months old but only this issue has occured for a few months.